# Expression with plus, equal, and greater than symbols in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand that an expression like `i += 1` usually means `i = i+1`...

What would the operation below mean?

`b += c > 0`

Comment: `c > 0` is a separate expression, could be `True` or `False`. `b += True` or `b += False`.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, `b += True` will increment b by 1 and `b += False` will not change the value of b.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- And technically, `c > 0` can be just about _anything_ (depending on the type of `c`).  For example, `numpy` uses this sort of thing to return boolean arrays...

Comment: Strictly speaking, `i += 1` is not an expression; it is an assignment statement with  a name (`i`) on one side and an expression (`1`) on the other. An expression can be a statement, but not vice versa.

Comment: @chepner thank you for clarifying this... for improving my understanding, would ``i=i+1`` be an expression that is also a statement?

Comment: No, that's still just a statement. Expression statements are expressions like `3` or `some_function("a")` used where a statement is expected. Typically, expression statements are only useful if the expression is a function call that has a side effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `x op = expression`,  is the syntax for shorthand `operators`. It will be evaluated like `x = x op` expression.

As said above in comments, "b += True will increment b by 1 and b += False will not change the value of b", It will see if c is bigger than 0, or not. if it is it will increment b by 1